# Web2py: How can i make the password field to display " * " or dots while the user is entering the password?

Tags: web, passwords, web2py

I am a naive programmer and currently using web2py to create a web app. In the website I ask the user to enter the password first. In the models section, in db.py I have written the following code for entering password:

```
db = DAL('sqlite://webform.sqlite')
db.define_table('register',
    Field('password', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(),IS_MATCH('somepassword',error_message='Invalid password')]));
```

Here, 'somepassword' is just a predefined password I have given for testing.

---

How can I make the field to display "*" or dots while the user is entering the password? like in the image given below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DAL has a password field type:

```
    Field('password', 'password', requires=CRYPT(min_length=8))
```

Password type fields by default get the `SQLFORM.widget.password.widget` widget in `SQLFORM`s (which you can also set manually on any field via the "widget" argument). The HTML input type will be set to "password".

As shown above, it is also recommended that you do not store passwords as plain text but instead store a hash of the password, which is what the `CRYPT` validator does (it can also be used to enforce a minimum password length). You can specify additional password complexity requirements via the [IS_STRONG](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Complexity-and-security-validators) validator (though make sure that validator is applied *before* the `CRYPT` validator, as the latter tranforms the password).